# How to select div by text content using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape some HTML from something like this. Sometimes the data I need is in div[0], sometimes div[1], etc.

Imagine everyone takes 3-5 classes. One of them is always Biology. Their report card is always alphabetized.  I want everybody's Biology grade.

I've already scraped all this HTML into a text, now how to fish out the Biology grades?

```
<div class = "student">
    <div class = "score">Algebra C-</div>
    <div class = "score">Biology A+</div>
    <div class = "score">Chemistry B</div>
</div>
<div class = "student">
    <div class = "score">Biology B</div>
    <div class = "score">Chemistry A</div>
</div>
<div class = "student">
    <div class = "score">Alchemy D</div>
    <div class = "score">Algebra A</div>
    <div class = "score">Biology B</div>
</div>
<div class = "student">
    <div class = "score">Algebra A</div>
    <div class = "score">Biology B</div>
    <div class = "score">Chemistry C+</div>
</div>
<div class = "student">
    <div class = "score">Alchemy D</div>
    <div class = "score">Algebra A</div>
    <div class = "score">Bangladeshi History C</div>
    <div class = "score">Biology B</div>
</div>
```

I'm using beautiful soup, and I think I'm going to have to find divs where Text includes "Biology"?

This is only for a quick scrape and I'm open to hard-coding and fiddling in Excel or whatnot. Yes, it's a shoddy website! Yes, they do have an API, and I don't know a thing about WDSL.

Short version: http://www.legis.ga.gov/Legislation/en-US/Search.aspx ,to find the date of last action on every bill, FWIW. It's troublesome because if a bill has no sponsors in the second chamber, instead of a div containing nothing, they just don't have a div there at all. So sometimes the timeline is in div 3, sometimes 2, etc.

Comment: Hey!  Good ol regex!  Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

(1) To just get the biology grade only, it is almost one liner.

```
import bs4, re
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
scores_string = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Biology')) 
scores = [score_string.split()[-1] for score_string in scores_string]
print scores_string
print scores
```

The output looks like this:

```
[u'Biology A+', u'Biology B', u'Biology B', u'Biology B', u'Biology B']
[u'A+', u'B', u'B', u'B', u'B']
```

(2) You locate the tags and maybe for further tasks, you need to find the `parent`:

```
import bs4, re
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
scores = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Biology'))
divs = [score.parent for score in scores]
print divs
```

Output looks like this:

```
[<div class="score">Biology A+</div>, 
<div class="score">Biology B</div>, 
<div class="score">Biology B</div>, 
<div class="score">Biology B</div>, 
<div class="score">Biology B</div>]
```

***In conclusion, you can use find_siblings/parent/...etc  to move around the HTML tree.***

More information about how to [navigate the tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree). 
And Good luck with your work.

Comment: `The 'text' argument to find()-type methods is deprecated. Use 'string' instead.`

Answer (score 8):

Another way (using css selector) is:

`divs = soup.select('div:-soup-contains("Biology")')`

EDIT:

**BeautifulSoup4 4.7.0+** (SoupSieve) **is required**

Comment: there is no ':contains' in CSS. And upon testing, bs4 rejects this also. Would have been immensely useful though.

Comment: @thelogix I've used this in several projects and it works like a charm.
Check what you're doing wrong in your code.

Comment: Here I've made for you a video preview how it works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNgTsMeYHsI

Comment: I've investigated further. That selector comes from a module called "SoupSieve", which works with bs4 version 4.7.0 and up. Also, if you install a new bs4 via pip, soupsieve also gets installed. Thats why you probably never noticed it. SoupSieve looks very very cool. It even adds selectors that aren't in official CSS, like your ":contains".

Comment: SO wont let me change my vote without a change to the answer. You could add that BS4 4.7.0+ and SoupSieve is required - which would make this the perfect answer IMO :)

Comment: Added to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Edited to pseudo class `-soup-contains` since `contains` is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

You can extract them searching for any `<div>` element that has `score` as `class` attribute value, and use a regular expression to extract its biology score:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import sys
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')

for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'score'}):
    t = re.search(r'Biology\s+(\S+)', div.string)
    if t: print(t.group(1))
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py htmlfile
```

That yields:

```
A+
B
B
B
B
```