# Delete block in HTML based on text

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML snippet below and I need to delete a block based on its text for example `Name: John`. I know I can do this with `decompose()` from BeautifulSoup using the class name `sample` but I cannot applied decompose because I have different block attributes as well as tag name but the text within has the same pattern. Is there any modules in `bs4` that can solve this?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sample">
        Name:<br>
        <b>John</b>
    </div>
<div>
```

result:

```
<div id="container"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To find tags based on inner text see [How to select div by text content using Beautiful Soup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293792/how-to-select-div-by-text-content-using-beautiful-soup)

Once you have the required div, you can simply call `decompose()`:

```py
html = '''<div id="container">
    <div class="sample">
        Name:<br>
        <b>John</b>
    </div>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
sample = soup.find(text=re.compile('Name'))
sample.parent.decompose()
print(soup.prettify())
```

Side note: notice that I fixed the closing tag for your "container" div!

Comment: I need to delete div.sample block not to clear the entire div#container. I have different tag and attributes for example `<div dir="ltr">`. In this case, tag and attributes should never be used but the pattern of text inside. That would be to delete a block based on text and not to delete a block based on attributes.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the link that you provided. That's a great help. :)