# Problem with webscraping google python beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am writing code:
i want to open some subpages which have been found.

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=python'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
list_sites = soup.select('a[href]')
print(len(list_sites))
```

i want to open for example site in google like 'python' and then open some first links, but i have a problem with function select. What i should put inside to find links to
subpage? like a: Polish Python Coders Group - News, Welcome to Python.org, ...
I tried to put: a[href], a, h3 class but it doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

is this you need?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urllib.parse
import lxml

def print_extracted_data_from_url(url):

    headers = {
        "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')


    for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
        head_link = container.a['href']
        print(head_link)

    return soup.select_one('a#pnnext')



next_page_node = print_extracted_data_from_url('https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=python')
```

Comment: yeah but "a" search me 80+ results, like a subpages google etc, not only results of "python" searching

Comment: you can filter these href, somethin like   if 'python' in href

Comment: i think its not the best way to solve this, and it seems to be really problematic

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293792/how-to-select-div-by-text-content-using-beautiful-soup

Comment: nope, it still doesnt work... i think its different problem

Comment: tryed soup.find_all("a", string="python")?

Comment: this work for me: links = soup.select('a:contains("python")')

Comment: but it only found 9 not 12 elements, its still wrong

Comment: how are you count?

Comment: well... tell me if you get, im tryng to

Comment: i count with link to 'video' but without its 9 its fine, but links still doesnt work, moreover two last are not links

Comment: look to my post

Comment: my god, now i have a problem with install lxml, when i try to add this package to project in pycharm i got "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:" Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'D:\msys2\mingw64\bin\python.exe'. But i did it...